# Simple text does not render properly in a html input tag from resx file

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, resx

In resx file I have an entry:

```
AccountRegisterSubmit = Create a new account
```

In my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Submit = @Resources.AccountRegisterSubmit;
}

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value=@ViewBag.Submit />
    </div>
```

HTML resulting is malformed

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" a="" new="" account="">
```

I need instead

```
<input type="submit" value="Create a new account">
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the quotes in the HTML input tag:

```
<input type="submit" value="@ViewBag.Submit" />
```

The `@` symbol will print out the value as-is, without quotes, so you currently end up with:

```
<input type="submit" value=Create a new account>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double quote the value so that it is treated as text

```
   <input type="submit" value="@ViewBag.Submit" />
```